# Remove Numbering of References Without Log Giving Errors

Tags: bibliographies

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
 {\Huge\bfseries\centering}{\thechapter\space}{0pt}{\Huge}
%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{40pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
 \fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt} % get rid of warning from fancyhdr
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{%
 \renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
}
%\usepackage[round, sort&compress, authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
 \begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \bibitem{threef}
Afify, A. Z., and Mohamed, O. A. (2020). A new three-parameter 
  exponential distribution with variable shapes for the hazard rate: 
   Estimation and applications. \textit {Mathematics,} \textbf{8}(1), 
   135.
  \bibitem{four}
   Afify, A. Z., Gemeay, A. M., and Ibrahim, N. A. (2020). The heavy- 
   tailed exponential distribution: risk measures, estimation, and 
    application to actuarial data. \textit {Mathematics,} \textbf{8}(8), 
    1276.
    \bibitem{five}
    Afify, A. Z., Suzuki, A. K., Zhang, C., and Nassar, M. (2021). On 
    three-parameter exponential distribution: properties, Bayesian and 
     non-Bayesian estimation based on complete and censored samples. 
     \textit{Communications in Statistics-Simulation and Computation,} 
      \textbf{50}(11), 3799-3819.
      \end{thebibliography}
     \end{document}
```

Please help me remove numbering of references in this above code.
I need the references single spaced and one space between references. Thank you.

Comment: Please be a little more specific.

Comment: It's recommended to explain what you want to do in the question itself, not just in the question title or buried in some comment inside the code.

Comment: I want to remove numbering in my references. If you could help I would be highly appreciative. I am using package natbib it however displays errors.

Comment: You could use the `author-title` style of `biblatex`.

Comment: How do I do this please? I am clueless on how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just want to remove the numbering and if you are not going to cite any of your references, you could alter the definition of the biblabel with

```
\def\@biblabel#1{}
```

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
 {\Huge\bfseries\centering}{\thechapter\space}{0pt}{\Huge}
%\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-10pt}{40pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
 \fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \setlength{\headheight}{14.49998pt} % get rid of warning from fancyhdr
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{%
 \renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
}
%\usepackage[round, sort&compress, authoryear]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
 \begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \bibitem{threef}
Afify, A. Z., and Mohamed, O. A. (2020). A new three-parameter 
  exponential distribution with variable shapes for the hazard rate: 
   Estimation and applications. \textit {Mathematics,} \textbf{8}(1), 
   135.
  \bibitem{four}
   Afify, A. Z., Gemeay, A. M., and Ibrahim, N. A. (2020). The heavy- 
   tailed exponential distribution: risk measures, estimation, and 
    application to actuarial data. \textit {Mathematics,} \textbf{8}(8), 
    1276.
    \bibitem{five}
    Afify, A. Z., Suzuki, A. K., Zhang, C., and Nassar, M. (2021). On 
    three-parameter exponential distribution: properties, Bayesian and 
     non-Bayesian estimation based on complete and censored samples. 
     \textit{Communications in Statistics-Simulation and Computation,} 
      \textbf{50}(11), 3799-3819.
      \end{thebibliography}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That caused me nightmares. Thank you

Comment: @MUIADOMINICMUTISO You're welcome!